# Unsure why video uploaded to S3 is 0 bits

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

After a few days of trying to upload a video to AWS, I have successfully (almost) been able to. The main problem I am seeing is when I head to my S3 bucket, the file has a `Size 0 B`. I was hoping to see what I might be doing wrong that is causing this to occur.

On the backend I get a presignedUrl such as:

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({
    accessKeyId: ACCESSKEY_ID,
    secretAccessKey: SECRETKEY
});

const s3Params = {
    Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
    Key: uuidv4() + '.mov',
    Expires: 60 * 10,
    ContentType: 'mov',
    ACL: 'public-read'
};

let url = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Params);
return { url };
```

Once I have the url for upload. On the frontend the way I am sending the file is:

```
const uploadFileToS3 = async (uri) => {
    const type = video.uri.split('.').pop();

    const respo = await fetch(uri, {
        method: 'PUT',
        body: {
            url: video.uri,
            type,
            name: 'testing'
        },
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': type,
            'x-amz-acl': 'public-read'
        }
    });
    const some = await JSON.stringify(respo);
```

It does seem to be saving something since I see it in the bucket but am unable to download or view it. Just shows an empty page and it feels like nothing (the video) possibly was uploaded to S3. Any pointers to where I might be going wrong in uploading a video to S3?

Thank you for all the help.

Comment: When you download it does it actually have zero bytes or does it have that JSON? It doesn't seem like you're sending the content anywhere, just the JSON.

Comment: An example [here](https://javascript.info/fetch) creates a blob first to upload using  fetch. Maybe your case you also need to do this?

Comment: To add on to both, `body` can't be a JavaScript object. It has to be a string, a blog, or one of the other supported formats. That's probably why your body ends up being empty. Either way like Marcin said you should read the data from the file and put that in body instead of a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Marcin That is actually what I needed to do. Thank you so much for this one. After I fetched it and converted to a blob, I am able to see the size and also watch the video from the bucket.

Comment: @No problem. If you don't mind I will provide an answer for future reference.

Comment: @kichik Thank you. That actually was what I needed to do. Now it is working perfectly. Appreciate all the help everyone has given me :)

Comment: @Marcin Please do but also mention what Kichik said that the body can't be an object but the file itself.

Comment: @kichik Provided more details. Thus maybe he should provide an answer for this one:-) Mine was more of a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not specify an URL when you upload a file. You need 2 fetches:

- the first one downloads the video from `video.uri`
- the second uploads the video to S3: `body: blob`

To download a file as a blob, use [response.blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/blob). Then you can use that to upload the file ([here is an example](https://github.com/sashee/s3_upload_signed_urls/blob/master/index.html#L33)).